# FabricJS Crop extended functionality

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, crop

Found this implementation of croping
https://editphotosforfree.com/photoapps/online-photo-editor-and-collage-maker
which is exactly what I want to use. But it looks like there is no example on the internet, which reproduces this functionality. Other cropping techniques in stack overflow and google searches have some principles of this implementation, but not the whole thing.
Any ideas how to achieve this?
[image]

Update1:
With some debugging I could transfer the code. But it is not perfect. The corners leave the bounderies and it will not work if you rotate the image. Maybe someone can "build" on this.

```
document.getElementById("crop").onclick = function () {
  var e = canvas.getActiveObject();
  if (e && e.get("type") == "image") {
    var i = new fabric.Rect({
        id: "crop-rect",
        top: e.top,
        left: e.left,
        width: e.getScaledWidth(),
        height: e.getScaledHeight(),
        stroke: "rgb(42, 67, 101)",
        strokeWidth: 2,
        strokeDashArray: [5, 5],
        fill: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)",
        globalCompositeOperation: "overlay",
      }),
      a = new fabric.Rect({
        id: "overlay-rect",
        top: e.top,
        left: e.left,
        width: e.getScaledWidth(),
        height: e.getScaledHeight(),
        selectable: !1,
        selection: !1,
        fill: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
      });
    if ((i.setControlVisible("mtr", !1), e.cropX)) {
      var s = e.cropX,
        o = e.cropY,
        c = e.width,
        l = e.height;
      e.set({
        cropX: null,
        cropY: null,
        left: e.left - s * e.scaleX,
        top: e.top - o * e.scaleY,
        width: e._originalElement.naturalWidth,
        height: e._originalElement.naturalHeight,
      }),
        (e.dirty = !0),
        i.set({
          left: e.left + s * e.scaleX,
          top: e.top + o * e.scaleY,
          width: c * e.scaleX,
          height: l * e.scaleY,
        }),
        (i.dirty = !0),
        a.set({
          left: e.left,
          top: e.top,
          width: e.width * e.scaleX,
          height: e.height * e.scaleY,
        }),
        (a.dirty = !0);
    }
    canvas.add(a),
      canvas.add(i),
      canvas.discardActiveObject(),
      canvas.setActiveObject(i),
      canvas.renderAll(),
      i.on("moving", function () {
        (i.top < e.top || i.left < e.left) &&
          ((i.left = i.left < e.left ? e.left : i.left),
          (i.top = i.top < e.top ? e.top : i.top)),
          (i.top + i.getScaledHeight() > e.top + e.getScaledHeight() ||
            i.left + i.getScaledWidth() > e.left + e.getScaledWidth()) &&
            ((i.top =
              i.top + i.getScaledHeight() > e.top + e.getScaledHeight()
                ? e.top + e.getScaledHeight() - i.getScaledHeight()
                : i.top),
            (i.left =
              i.left + i.getScaledWidth() > e.left + e.getScaledWidth()
                ? e.left + e.getScaledWidth() - i.getScaledWidth()
                : i.left));
      }),
      i.on("deselected", function () {
        h();
      });
  }

  function h(r, n) {
    var s = (i.left - e.left) / e.scaleX,
      o = (i.top - e.top) / e.scaleY,
      c = (i.width * i.scaleX) / e.scaleX,
      l = (i.height * i.scaleY) / e.scaleY;
    e.set("cropX", s),
      e.set("cropY", o),
      e.set("width", c),
      e.set("height", l),
      canvas.remove(i),
      canvas.remove(a),
      e.set({
        top: e.top + o * e.scaleY,
        left: e.left + s * e.scaleX,
      });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

there is definitely no whole thing for that , the only way is to take example you been able to find and modify it , or do it from scratch , it is sad, but it is true.The trick is to set right cropX,cropY,height,width to the image ,accordingly to offsets to background image , which is clone of initial one